# Joomla K2 - how do you read the value of an extra field in a module?

Tags: joomla-k2

I have the Joomla K2 plugin installed. Is there a way to read the value of an article's K2 Extra Field from a module? I just need to read the value in PHP from within a module's default.php file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the K2 content module to pull all of the current items data for display in a module position. It supports subtemplates and data displayed can be selected through the module parameters so you should be able to display anything you want in the module. This module is dependent on being displayed on a K2 item page to work since it pulls the content based on the current item ID. You can get that module here - [K2 BNR Module](http://bnrextensions.googlecode.com/files/mod_k2bnr_content.zip)

Otherwise, you can use the standard K2 Content module. You can choose your content from categories, specific items, or even a single item. Then use the parameters and template options to display the content as needed. This does not require the module to be on a K2 item page as it selects the items to display on its own.

Comment: Thanks, Brent. I'm going to download your BNR Module. On the second option you listed, can you explain "parameters and template options"? I'm new to Joomla and K2, so please forgive my ignorance :)

Comment: When you add a new instance of the module, you can pick which parts of the content display, those are the parameters. The module also has a template that determines how the module displays. You can add more templates and choose which one you want to use, also in the module parameters. This makes it very flexible  for displaying content where and how you want.

Comment: This is a really good module, is it posible to use it to show the gallery in a module position?

Comment: It doesn't show the gallery currently, but that is a good idea. I will add that as a feature request.